# Can't access Rails app in production after Kamal deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, server, ruby-on-rails-7, kamal

I'm using [Kamal](https://kamal-deploy.org/) (old MRSK) with Rails and I'm able to run `kamal deploy` with success.

However, I'm having issues accessing the website in production after deployment: when I access the website URL [www.theaddress.com](http://www.theaddress.com) (or the IP of the set up NodeBalancer at 139.144.161.121), I get "This site can't be reached" in the browser.

How to solve the issue? What to check?

This is the deploy.yml:

```
service: my-app

image: myusername/my-app

servers:
  web:
    hosts:
      - 172.104.234.79
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.domain.rule: "Host(`www.theaddress.com`) || Host(`theaddress.com`)"
      traefik.http.routers.domain.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.domain.tls.certresolver: letsencrypt
    options:
      "add-host": host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    cmd: "./bin/rails server"

# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  # server: registry.digitalocean.com / ghcr.io / ...
  username: myusername
  # Always use an access token rather than real password when possible.
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

# Inject ENV variables into containers (secrets come from .env).
# Remember to run `kamal env push` after making changes!
env:
  clear:
    DB_HOST: 172.105.246.172
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

# Use accessory services (secrets come from .env).
accessories:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    host: 172.105.246.172
    port: 3306
    env:
      clear:
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      secret:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    files:
      # - config/mysql/production.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - db/production.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: 'mysqld'

# Configure custom arguments for Traefik
traefik:
  options:
    publish:
      - "443:443"
    volume:
      - "/letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json"
  args:
    entryPoints.web.address: ":80"
    entryPoints.websecure.address: ":443"
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to: websecure
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme: https
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email: "info@rtsrl.eu"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint: web
    # accesslog: true
    # accesslog.format: json

volumes:
  - "/storage:/rails/storage"
```

This is the deployment logs:

```
Mac:my-app MyUser$ kamal deploy
  INFO [53a9c61c] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [53a9c61c] Finished in 1.014 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Acquiring the deploy lock...
Log into image registry...
  INFO [184dab6a] Running docker login -u [REDACTED] -p [REDACTED] as MyUser@localhost
  INFO [184dab6a] Finished in 1.489 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [5ee83758] Running docker login -u [REDACTED] -p [REDACTED] on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [5ee83758] Finished in 1.080 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Build and push app image...
  INFO [8a5f900e] Running docker --version && docker buildx version as MyUser@localhost
  INFO [8a5f900e] Finished in 0.165 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [5eabb8dd] Running docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --builder kamal-my-app-multiarch -t myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 -t myusername/my-app:latest --label service="my-app" --file Dockerfile . as MyUser@localhost
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd] Command: docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --builder kamal-my-app-multiarch -t myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 -t myusername/my-app:latest --label service="my-app" --file Dockerfile .
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #0 building with "kamal-my-app-multiarch" instance using docker-container driver
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #1 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #1 transferring dockerfile: 2.66kB done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #1 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #2 [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #2 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #3 DONE 1.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #4 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:ac85f380a63b13dfcefa89046420e1781752bab202122f8f50032edf31be0021
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #4 resolve docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:ac85f380a63b13dfcefa89046420e1781752bab202122f8f50032edf31be0021 done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #4 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #5 [auth] library/ruby:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #5 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #6 [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.2-slim
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #6 DONE 1.2s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #7 [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.2-slim
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #7 DONE 1.2s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #8 [internal] load .dockerignore
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #8 transferring context: 782B done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #8 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #9 [linux/arm64 base 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.2-slim@sha256:96a9448e3831916d0cfff20a1283d1266558cea4ee3b9969f63733b254ee8f6b
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #9 resolve docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.2-slim@sha256:96a9448e3831916d0cfff20a1283d1266558cea4ee3b9969f63733b254ee8f6b 0.0s done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #9 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #10 [linux/amd64 base 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.2-slim@sha256:96a9448e3831916d0cfff20a1283d1266558cea4ee3b9969f63733b254ee8f6b
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #10 resolve docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.2-slim@sha256:96a9448e3831916d0cfff20a1283d1266558cea4ee3b9969f63733b254ee8f6b 0.0s done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #10 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #11 [internal] load build context
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #11 transferring context: 368.06kB 0.2s done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #11 DONE 0.2s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #12 [linux/arm64 build 5/6] RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #12 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #13 [linux/arm64 base 4/5] RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #13 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #14 [linux/arm64 build 2/6] COPY --link Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #14 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #15 [linux/arm64 stage-2 1/4] RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl default-mysql-client imagemagick libvips &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #15 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #16 [linux/arm64 stage-2 3/4] COPY --from=build /rails /rails
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #16 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #17 [linux/arm64 build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #17 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #18 [linux/arm64 build 3/6] RUN bundle install &&     bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile &&     rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "/usr/local/bundle"/ruby/*/cache "/usr/local/bundle"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #18 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #19 [linux/arm64 base 3/5] RUN gem update --system --no-document &&     gem install -N bundler
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #19 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #20 [linux/arm64 base 2/5] WORKDIR /rails
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #20 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #21 [linux/arm64 build 1/6] RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev git libvips
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #21 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #22 [linux/arm64 build 4/6] COPY --link . .
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #22 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #23 [linux/arm64 stage-2 2/4] COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #23 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #24 [linux/arm64 base 5/5] RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ &&     /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "16.19.1" /usr/local/node &&     rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #24 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #25 [linux/arm64 stage-2 4/4] RUN groupadd --system --gid 1000 rails &&     useradd rails --uid 1000 --gid 1000 --create-home --shell /bin/bash &&     chown -R 1000:1000 db log storage tmp
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #25 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #26 [linux/amd64 build 3/6] RUN bundle install &&     bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile &&     rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "/usr/local/bundle"/ruby/*/cache "/usr/local/bundle"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #26 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #27 [linux/amd64 stage-2 1/4] RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl default-mysql-client imagemagick libvips &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #27 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #28 [linux/amd64 build 1/6] RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev git libvips
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #28 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #29 [linux/amd64 build 4/6] COPY --link . .
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #29 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #30 [linux/amd64 stage-2 2/4] COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #30 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #31 [linux/amd64 base 2/5] WORKDIR /rails
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #31 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #32 [linux/amd64 base 4/5] RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #32 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #33 [linux/amd64 base 3/5] RUN gem update --system --no-document &&     gem install -N bundler
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #33 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #34 [linux/amd64 base 5/5] RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ &&     /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "16.19.1" /usr/local/node &&     rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #34 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #35 [linux/amd64 build 5/6] RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #35 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #36 [linux/amd64 stage-2 3/4] COPY --from=build /rails /rails
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #36 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #37 [linux/amd64 build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #37 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #38 [linux/amd64 build 2/6] COPY --link Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #38 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #39 [linux/amd64 stage-2 4/4] RUN groupadd --system --gid 1000 rails &&     useradd rails --uid 1000 --gid 1000 --create-home --shell /bin/bash &&     chown -R 1000:1000 db log storage tmp
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #39 CACHED
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting to image
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting layers done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting manifest sha256:1d69c2bb5b4f1293b4921d7b14e65831d1bc76cc79ac8cb7199e136a5646724d done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting config sha256:bbcc7b99c47fda160ac584fa28612e05cad004b48bb13305b7670a54637dd870 done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting attestation manifest sha256:3b5eb2f3905f0ae37058165202d78fc1f61eafea87f015957513c6949f1490e6 done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting manifest sha256:5e137dbcce070ead929bd932299d11356bf1edbef2c2ac2c8e3b3f7d51b9e7ec done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting config sha256:042a2461aa1509f0108c19de3fb8faeb6b593332bc06a256a76862fa3b1656a6 done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting attestation manifest sha256:f6380a15792a601c4e109722038d085299bf8021e55b09a04ad3ecf90637301a done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting manifest list sha256:48dd67afb9c520946ab1831b3cdb8c43ef145bc561795d2f8f1db236922f2263
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 ...
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #41 [auth] myusername/my-app:pull,push token for registry-1.docker.io
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #41 DONE 0.0s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting to image
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 exporting manifest list sha256:48dd67afb9c520946ab1831b3cdb8c43ef145bc561795d2f8f1db236922f2263 done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 pushing layers
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 pushing layers 3.0s done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 pushing manifest for docker.io/myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90@sha256:48dd67afb9c520946ab1831b3cdb8c43ef145bc561795d2f8f1db236922f2263
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 pushing manifest for docker.io/myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90@sha256:48dd67afb9c520946ab1831b3cdb8c43ef145bc561795d2f8f1db236922f2263 2.3s done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 pushing layers 1.8s done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 pushing manifest for docker.io/myusername/my-app:latest@sha256:48dd67afb9c520946ab1831b3cdb8c43ef145bc561795d2f8f1db236922f2263
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 pushing manifest for docker.io/myusername/my-app:latest@sha256:48dd67afb9c520946ab1831b3cdb8c43ef145bc561795d2f8f1db236922f2263 1.3s done
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   #40 DONE 8.4s
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   
 DEBUG [5eabb8dd]   View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/kamal-my-app-multiarch/kamal-my-app-multiarch0/t8qe2yzq6o9xzt3co3q153rgb
  INFO [5eabb8dd] Finished in 11.154 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [5a2d3c5e] Running docker image rm --force myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [5a2d3c5e] Finished in 3.140 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e168f3fc] Running docker pull myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [e168f3fc] Finished in 38.731 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b1584e2a] Running docker inspect -f '{{ .Config.Labels.service }}' myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 | grep -x my-app || (echo "Image myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 is missing the `service` label" && exit 1) on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [b1584e2a] Finished in 0.284 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Ensure Traefik is running...
  INFO [274367b8] Running docker login -u [REDACTED] -p [REDACTED] on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [274367b8] Finished in 1.338 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [38885fe7] Running docker container start traefik || docker run --name traefik --detach --restart unless-stopped --publish 80:80 --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --env-file .kamal/env/traefik/traefik.env --log-opt max-size="10m" --label traefik.http.routers.catchall.entryPoints="http" --label traefik.http.routers.catchall.rule="PathPrefix(\`/\`)" --label traefik.http.routers.catchall.service="unavailable" --label traefik.http.routers.catchall.priority="1" --label traefik.http.services.unavailable.loadbalancer.server.port="0" --publish "443:443" --volume "/letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json" traefik:v2.9 --providers.docker --log.level="DEBUG" --entryPoints.web.address=":80" --entryPoints.websecure.address=":443" --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to="websecure" --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme="https" --entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email="info@rtsrl.eu" --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage="/letsencrypt/acme.json" --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge --certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint="web" on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [38885fe7] Finished in 0.276 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Ensure app can pass healthcheck...
  INFO [f688f569] Running docker run --detach --name healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 --publish 3999:3000 --label service=healthcheck-my-app -e KAMAL_CONTAINER_NAME="healthcheck-my-app" --env-file .kamal/env/roles/my-app-web.env --health-cmd "curl -f http://localhost:3000/up || exit 1" --health-interval "1s" --volume /storage:/rails/storage --add-host "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 ./bin/rails server on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [f688f569] Finished in 1.214 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [ce71d1e9] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [ce71d1e9] Finished in 0.332 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (starting), retrying in 1s (attempt 1/7)...
  INFO [f7f5ee86] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [f7f5ee86] Finished in 0.243 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (starting), retrying in 2s (attempt 2/7)...
  INFO [16473e92] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [16473e92] Finished in 0.309 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (starting), retrying in 3s (attempt 3/7)...
  INFO [e307e898] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [e307e898] Finished in 0.272 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (unhealthy), retrying in 4s (attempt 4/7)...
  INFO [b8e26cf8] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [b8e26cf8] Finished in 0.245 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (unhealthy), retrying in 5s (attempt 5/7)...
  INFO [71c8ccd7] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [71c8ccd7] Finished in 0.242 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (unhealthy), retrying in 6s (attempt 6/7)...
  INFO [578edb76] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [578edb76] Finished in 0.193 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO Container is healthy!
  INFO [ae4cb242] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker stop on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [ae4cb242] Finished in 0.607 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e4f32e2d] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^healthcheck-my-app-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker container rm on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [e4f32e2d] Finished in 0.417 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Detect stale containers...
  INFO [dfd984d8] Running docker ps --filter label=service=my-app --filter label=role=web --format "{{.Names}}" | while read line; do echo ${line#my-app-web-}; done on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [dfd984d8] Finished in 0.216 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Start container with version 14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 using a 7s readiness delay (or reboot if already running)...
  INFO [97569318] Running docker tag myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 myusername/my-app:latest on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [97569318] Finished in 0.216 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [92a3826c] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [92a3826c] Finished in 0.210 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [dbc51130] Running docker ps --filter label=service=my-app --filter label=role=web --filter status=running --filter status=restarting --latest --format "{{.Names}}" | while read line; do echo ${line#my-app-web-}; done on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [dbc51130] Finished in 0.215 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [949466e0] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal/cords/my-app-web-40814293ac0aac3709d68c7d70fbe265 ; touch .kamal/cords/my-app-web-40814293ac0aac3709d68c7d70fbe265/cord on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [949466e0] Finished in 0.181 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [94988e3a] Running docker run --detach --restart unless-stopped --name my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 --hostname 172.104.234.79-a386542f4b38 -e KAMAL_CONTAINER_NAME="my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90" -e KAMAL_VERSION="14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90" --env-file .kamal/env/roles/my-app-web.env --health-cmd "(curl -f http://localhost:3000/up || exit 1) && (stat /tmp/kamal-cord/cord > /dev/null || exit 1)" --health-interval "1s" --volume $(pwd)/.kamal/cords/my-app-web-40814293ac0aac3709d68c7d70fbe265:/tmp/kamal-cord --log-opt max-size="10m" --volume /storage:/rails/storage --label service="my-app" --label role="web" --label traefik.http.services.my-app-web.loadbalancer.server.scheme="http" --label traefik.http.routers.my-app-web.rule="PathPrefix(\`/\`)" --label traefik.http.routers.my-app-web.priority="2" --label traefik.http.middlewares.my-app-web-retry.retry.attempts="5" --label traefik.http.middlewares.my-app-web-retry.retry.initialinterval="500ms" --label traefik.http.routers.my-app-web.middlewares="my-app-web-retry@docker" --label traefik.http.routers.domain.rule="Host(\`themy.com\`)" --label traefik.http.routers.domain.entrypoints="websecure" --label traefik.http.routers.domain.tls.certresolver="letsencrypt" --add-host "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" myusername/my-app:14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90 ./bin/rails server on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [94988e3a] Finished in 0.713 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [29666cce] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [29666cce] Finished in 0.350 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (starting), retrying in 1s (attempt 1/7)...
  INFO [8a5f4743] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [8a5f4743] Finished in 0.242 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (starting), retrying in 2s (attempt 2/7)...
  INFO [215cb1c4] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [215cb1c4] Finished in 0.290 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (unhealthy), retrying in 3s (attempt 3/7)...
  INFO [cdcb2c17] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [cdcb2c17] Finished in 0.273 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (unhealthy), retrying in 4s (attempt 4/7)...
  INFO [94b6e11e] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [94b6e11e] Finished in 0.286 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO container not ready (unhealthy), retrying in 5s (attempt 5/7)...
  INFO [e0c735ca] Running docker container ls --all --filter name=^my-app-web-14ef25d341406b48b05911ddeb90aaf374f7fc90$ --quiet | xargs docker inspect --format '{{if .State.Health}}{{.State.Health.Status}}{{else}}{{.State.Status}}{{end}}' on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [e0c735ca] Finished in 0.250 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO Container is healthy!
Prune old containers and images...
  INFO [51e81670] Running docker ps -q -a --filter label=service=my-app --filter status=created --filter status=exited --filter status=dead | tail -n +6 | while read container_id; do docker rm $container_id; done on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [51e81670] Finished in 0.259 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [8a14540d] Running docker container prune --force --filter label=service=healthcheck-my-app on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [8a14540d] Finished in 0.244 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [0f1fe558] Running docker image prune --force --filter label=service=my-app on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [0f1fe558] Finished in 0.244 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [289eab55] Running docker image ls --filter label=service=my-app --format '{{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | grep -v -w "$(docker container ls -a --format '{{.Image}}\|' --filter label=service=my-app | tr -d '\n')myusername/my-app:latest\|myusername/my-app:<none>" | while read image tag; do docker rmi $tag; done on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [289eab55] Finished in 0.348 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Releasing the deploy lock...
  Finished all in 109.8 seconds
```

More info:

```
$ kamal app exec -i bash
Get most recent version available as an image...
Launching interactive command with version latest via SSH from new container on 172.104.234.79...
rails@cbffec8f3246:/rails$ bin/rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.2 application starting in production 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 6.4.0 (ruby 3.2.2-p53) ("The Eagle of Durango")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: production
*          PID: 8
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

```
$ kamal app exec 'bin/rails about'
Get most recent version available as an image...
Launching command with version latest from new container...
  INFO [1817bbb8] Running docker run --rm --env-file .kamal/env/roles/my-app-web.env --volume /storage:/rails/storage --add-host "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" myusername/my-app:latest bin/rails about on 172.104.234.79
  INFO [1817bbb8] Finished in 11.727 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
App Host: 172.104.234.79
About your application's environment
Rails version             7.1.2
Ruby version              ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems version          3.5.1
Rack version              3.0.8
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
Middleware                ActionDispatch::AssumeSSL, Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Executor, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ContentSecurityPolicy::Middleware, ActionDispatch::PermissionsPolicy::Middleware, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, Rack::TempfileReaper, Rack::LocaleMemorable, Warden::Manager, Rack::Attack
Application root          /rails
Environment               production
Database adapter          mysql2
Database schema version   20231213030434
```

Comment: The deployment logs.

Comment: Deployment logs added. +1 ;)

Comment: What about deploy.yml? Here we can't see if you have any traefik configs.

Comment: @Levara deploy.yml added. I'm using traefik.

Comment: @user502052 did you end up fixing it, I have the same issue

Comment: Yes, but I don't remember how. It took me over a week to get Kamal working. Good luck! Be strong!